# In Angular-4 ng-serve didn't re-render the changes in a file?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular4-forms

I am new to Angular-4, the problem is every time i make some changes in a file, `ng serve` didn't re-render the changes and it's very annoying to restart `ng serve` every time and its time consuming, according to the documentation of Angular-4, It should re-render the changes in a file automatically but it didn't work in my project, please tell me is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Are you using angular CLI?

Comment: Yes I am using angular CLI

Comment: Can you create a new project with `ng new test-project` and verify that it doesn't work with a blank installation?

Comment: I done that already

Comment: And did it not work then either? Are you using the most recent version of the CLI - you can check with `ng -v`

Comment: No, It didn't work.

Comment: Try npm cache clean

Answer (score 0):

1. If you add any external files then you need to re-render.
2. After making changes please save it. It will re- render itself.

Comment: No, i didn't add any external files and it didn't re-render after saving.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work sometimes?  My team and myself frequently have to hit enter in the cli for it to do anything.  It's as if it's waiting for user input to render new content.

If that doesn't sound like your issue, delete node_modules and run npm install again.  Also keep an eye out for any errors in console or during initial ng serve.